# Correct interpretation of SQL request by EF Core

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a certain table in the database that stores the following objects:

```
public partial class Invoice
{
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public string DocumentReference { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Certificate { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a query that returns me the number of specific elements:

```
SELECT Count(*)
        FROM (
                SELECT DocumentNumber,DocumentDate,DocumentReference
                FROM vInvoiceSwivelInfoWeb
                WHERE Email = 'someemail@gmail.com' AND Language = 'FR'
                GROUP BY DocumentNumber,DocumentDate,DocumentReference
            ) AS T
```

The answer looks something like this: [image]

How to use EF to make such a request and get a numerical answer?
I tried like this:

`_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($"..some SQL query..")`

but I do not get the expected result.

**UPD:** Having received the answer about the impossibility of fulfilling this request through EF, the following question reasonably arose: **Is it possible to make this request using LINQ?**

Comment: about your UPD question:  the answer is yes and no. you can create a `view` for your custom query and use a mapped entity to that view to get the result using EF-Core and Linq but you can not use SQL command and LINQ without a `view`. I'll update the answer if you needed.

Comment: oO.i think I misunderstood your question.  if you want to create that query using LINQ yes it is possible.

Comment: @AliReza, It would be great to add this solution to your answer.

Comment: check that LINQ query I've added to answer. it should work. I couldn't test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Leverage `ADO.NET` via the `Context.Database` property.
Unfortunately, there is no way to get the count from the database using EF Core execute methods if you have a custom query that is not related to your entities.

```cs
using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) From Table1";
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // do something with result
    }
}
```

---

**for Updated question**

```cs
    var count = from a in _context.vInvoiceSwivelInfoWeb
                where a.Email == "someemail@gmail.com" && a.Language == "FR"
                group new { a.DocumentNumber , a.DocumentReference , a.DocumentDate } by a into g
                select g.Count()
```

also, it's important to know which version of EF-Core are you using: 
currently, if you are using EF-Core 3 `group-by` doesn't translate to SQL command so you have to do it on client-side:

check this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

for EF-Core 3.0 - 3.1.1

```cs
var count = _context.vInvoiceSwivelInfoWeb
                 .Where(a => a.Email == "someemail@gmail.com" && a.Language == "FR" ).ToList()
                 .GroupBy(a => new { a.DocumentNumber ,a.DocumentDate, a.DocumentReference }).Count();
```

Comment: it works, but returns the wrong value. In your case it is 56

Comment: can you check what is wrong in generated sql? you have to enable `options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()` of your context first.

Comment: what version of EF are you using?

Comment: my vers. ef core 3.1.1

Comment: It seems to me that your request lacks another "select". but I'm not sure, since I don't know LINQ very well